# Android : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) on new FileWriter on a first application launch

Tags: android, filewriter, enoent

In the following method, I have an exception ( *open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)* ) in `new FileWriter(f.getPath())` **ONLY on the first application launch after installation (then - close and reopen the app - it works)** :

```
public static boolean writeContent(File f, String s) {

    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f.getPath()))) {
        writer.write(s);
        writer.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    }
```

I have the following permission in the manifest :

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

File is defined with a method `getExternalFilesDir()` and  with `<external-files-path>` in the file_paths.xml file.

Any idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: You should only call that function after you got runtime permission for write.

Comment: Sorry.. no permissions needed  for `File is defined with a method getExternalFilesDir()`. Please put that on the first line of your post ...

Comment: `and with <external-files-path>` FileProvider stuff has nothing to do with it.

Comment: `I have an exception ( open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) )` Please post the relevant logcat lines.

Comment: Also tell were and when you call that function.